# Custom Framework Always include in Embedded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Custom Framework Always include in Embedded Section is there another way instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must embed dynamic frameworks, because they are based on a shared library, and shared libraries are loaded at runtime. You could create a static framework wich contains a static library. Static libs are linked at build time, and thus they must not embedded into your app.

Comment: is there any way to load dynamic framework at runtime?

Comment: Yes, you may load dynamic frameworks with `NSBundle`, or `dlopen`(3) if you like it more low-level. On an iOS device the dynamic libraries must be code-signed.

Comment: I got Below error while submitting app to app store.

1) ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for sample.app/Frameworks/customFramework.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."

2) ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. 
3) ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid.

4) WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/sample.app/Frameworks/customFramework.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable.

Comment: Dynamic linking needs _position independent code_ (PIC), which in simple terms means, that addresses are relative and not absolute. You can control this with the compiler switches `-fpic` and `-fPIC`. The first error means, that you have included the framework binary for the simulator. You should send a binary which only contains ARM code. Why don't you create the framework binary with a standard Xcode target?

Comment: Thanks a lot macmoonshine